# I created a tag in my team, why does it have a description from public Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, bug, tags, stack-overflow-for-teams

Should tags we create on Teams be used across the Stack Exchange network?

For instance, we created our first question and one of the tags I used was [wifi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wifi).
When I went to the tags (specifically for my team) I see a description I would not expect to see:

[image: Tags in a team, with an arrow highlighting the tag description of the wifi tag.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wow I found the answer:

> This tag's information is synced with public stack overflow.  By
>   editing this tag and saving your changes, you will create a new tag
>   that will only be used within this team.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

It's actually by design.

One of the goals of Teams is to integrate the information into Stack Overflow for the members of the Team. If you search for a specific tag in the search bar, it will return **both** Teams and Stack Overflow content in the search results. This saves you from having to search in two places to get the information you need.

That said, not all Stack Overflow tags are going to be useful to a Team and some Teams may need custom tags of their own to categorize their questions. To help with this, there are two types of tags on Teams. You can see them in your screenshot.

- Tags with a border are Team-specific
- Tags with no border are Stack Overflow tags

You can always edit the tag Excerpts and Wikis to match your local Team-specific usage of the tag. Doing so will convert the tag from the unbordered to the bordered tag style. If you only edit one, the tag will convert but the general SO text will remain visible. There's no way to remove the text without replacing it.

If the tag is Team-specific, it *will* still show up in a tag search if it also exists on Stack Overflow, so don't worry about losing that functionality if you edit the tag information.

If you want to limit results to SO only or a Team only, click the "Tags" link in the sidebar for the section you want to search and find the tag name there.

Comment: Yep got it see my answer above.  I think I am liking this tool!

Comment: Couldn't have answered better myself. Gotta admit that I'm pretty proud of this functionality. I think the team nailed this.

Comment: @JoeFriend Thanks for the compliment! I do think it's a great feature. The one thing I'd love is a way to clear the text without having to enter new text but, otherwise, I think it's really well done.