# Community user uses [meta] tag for Stack Overflow Teams incorrectly

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-for-teams

I've recently begun using SO Teams for a private team. The interface starts with several useful questions on etiquette and various "meta" topics.

Those questions are all tagged with the `meta` tag.  However, the description is odd:

> Meta elements are the HTML or XHTML element used to provide structured metadata about a Web page. DO NOT USE this tag for questions about Stack Overflow; post these on meta.stackoverflow.com instead.

This seems to suggest that this tag was incorrectly used by the default "community" user. There are other questions coming up that are appropriately "meta" in the sense that they involve the usage of the site itself.

What is the most appropriate tag to use? If there is a generic tag that is also available on public SO, I would like to stay consistent. The general instruction doesn't seem to apply because our teams "meta" tag should really be kept Private.

Comment: So that tag description is based on the [tag:meta] tag from the main Stack Overflow.  I assume teams uses the exact same tags.  Probably an oversight when they defaulted to using "meta" for teams meta questions

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368393/i-created-a-tag-in-my-team-why-does-it-have-a-description-from-public-stack-ove/368395#368395 That said, if the Community user is going to use the Meta tag by default, it should probably come with an *actual* team-specific tag wiki/excerpt.